# Animation moves other elements

Tags: html, css

Hi I have a problem with animations on my website. I have two divs one have 100% height and if i hover on it it get down 2 rems and all other content under this element is going down too. How can I fix it? Here is link to simple example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t8sg2eca/1/)

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
 }

.item {
    height: 75px;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #555;
 }
.item:hover{
    margin-top: 2rem;
 }
```

```html
<body>
   <section>
       <div class="container">
           <div class="item">Some content</div>
           <div class="item">Some content</div>
           <div class="item">Some content</div>
           <div class="item">Some content</div>
       </div>
       <div class="body">
           <div class="content">
                <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                </p>
           </div>
       </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably better to use `transform` on those elements.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
 }

.item {
    height: 75px;
    width: 25%;
    background-color: #555;
    transition: transform .3s ease;
 }
.item:hover{
    transform: translateY(2rem);
 }
```

```html
<body>
   <section>
       <div class="container">
           <div class="item">Some content</div>
           <div class="item">Some content</div>
           <div class="item">Some content</div>
           <div class="item">Some content</div>
       </div>
       <div class="body">
           <div class="content">
                <p>
                     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                </p>
           </div>
       </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to always render some `margin-bottom` on each `.item`. Then, on hover, move the `margin-bottom` to `margin-top` so the element is moved, but takes the same amount of space, this way your text below the div's wont move:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.item {
  height: 75px;
  width: 25%;
  background-color: #555;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
.item:hover{
  margin-top: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="item">Some content</div>
    <div class="item">Some content</div>
    <div class="item">Some content</div>
    <div class="item">Some content</div>
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
</body>
```